# Is there any quantity related to $\cos \left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{C-A}{2}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$

Tags: geometry, triangles

While doing an inequality, I encountered the following expression,where $ABC$ is a triangle: $$\cos \left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{C-A}{2}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

So my question is do you know some quantites related to that expression (or even the individual terms or something related) in a triangle?

It could be better if its in terms of $R$ and $r$ :)

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, your expression is equal to $$2\cos\left(\frac{B-C}4\right)\cos\left(\frac{C-A}4\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}4\right)-1$$ but I don't see whether that is of any use.

Comment: It seems not possible to rewrite that expression in terms of incircle and circumcircle radius alone. Since it only uses angles, it has to be indifferent under scaling, so you might assume $R=1$. For various triangles with the same $r$, the expression gives different values, though, so it is not fully defined by incircle and circumcircle.

Comment: @MvG Ok, no prob :) By that line, I meant that $r$ and $R$ in it would have helped, its not necessary that the expression be only in $r$ and $R$. Thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not clear enough to give a complete answer but I can give you a hint that might help. The altitude and diameter drawn from $A$ form angle of measure $\angle B-\angle C$ whose bisector coincides with the bisector of $\angle BAC$. Now let $M$ be the intersection of the bisector of $\angle BAC$ and the circumcircle. It is easy to verify that $\cos(\frac{\angle B -\angle C}{2})=\frac {AM}{2R}$. You can obtain similar terms for vertices $B$ and $C$ as well. Now see if you can express $AM$ (and the analogous terms for $B$ and $C$) in a way you'd like to have.